# How to do a unit test for Http get MockBackend in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular

**How to do a unit test for Http get MockBackend in Angular2?**

I'm having trouble testing my http unit test.
Every time I look at `MockBackend` it seems confusing, a lot of code and some imports never work.

I just want a very basic http get unit test

I'm using: typescript, angular2, jasmine and karma runner.

My actual code works fine.

**Here is my code that I'm testing:**

```
 import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

 @Injectable()

 export class FirebaseService{
   headers: Headers;

   //Test issue seems to be here when I inject Http instance.
   constructor(public http?: Http) {  
     this.headers = new Headers();
     this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   }

   //This is the method I'm testing.
   public getSpotifyTracks = ():Promise<Object> =>{ 
       return this.http
        .get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem',      {headers:this.headers})
        .map((response) => {
           return response.json()
        }).toPromise();  
   }

 }
```

**Here is my unit test for that code:**

```
import {it, iit, describe, expect, inject, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick} from 'angular2/testing';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {FirebaseService} from '../app/firebase-service';

describe('Firebase Service Calls', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(()=> [Http, FirebaseService]); 

    //Issue seems to be here????
    it('get all tracks from spotify', injectAsync([FirebaseService],(service) => {      

        return service.getSpotifyTracks().then((response) => {
          expect(response.length).not.toBe(null);
        });   

    }), 3000);

});
```

Comment: Here you have an [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5575).

Comment: Hi Eric could you do a unit test for my code above as an answer? I had a look at the link and still couldn't get it working the unit test

Comment: Here is a very simple and functional example http://stackoverflow.com/a/37733428/2375648

Comment: HTTP unit testing using Angular2 final release - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108504/how-to-write-an-http-mock-unit-test-in-angular-2-final-release

Answer (score 4):

First import all modules :

```
import {it,describe,expect,inject,injectAsync,beforeEachProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {provide, Injector} from 'angular2/core';

import {MockBackend} from 'angular2/http/testing';
import {YourServiceToBeTested} from 'path/to/YourServiceToBeTested';
```

Next you need to declare the Mocked HttpBackend :

```
describe('Service with Http injected', () => {
beforeEachProviders(() => {
[
  MockBackend,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  provide(
      Http,
         {
            useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => {
              return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
       },
       deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
  }),
  YourServiceToBeTested
]
});
```

Finally on each test, you need to inject the mock & set the mocked value (ie the fake data returned by your service for this specific test)

```
it('should respect your expectation',

inject(
  [YourServiceToBeTested, MockBackend],
  (yourServiceToBeTested, mockBackend) => {

    let response = 'Expected Response from HTTP service usually JSON format';
    let responseOptions = new ResponseOptions({body: response});
mock.connections.subscribe(
    c => c.mockRespond(new Response(responseOptions)));

    var res = yourServiceToBeTested.ServiceMethodToBeTest(serviceParams);
    expect(res).toEqual('your own expectation');
  }));
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I followed [this blog post](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-http-services-angular-2-jasmine/)

Answer (score 2):

While @f-del s answer gets the same result this is easier and uses Angulars DI better.

```
describe('Firebase Service Calls', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(()=> [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        MockBackend,
        provide(XHRBackend, {useExisting: MockBackend})]);
```

This way, when `Http` is requested, and instance that uses `MockBackend` is provided.

Comment: i'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
     at Object.parse (native)` while using above code (not passing `json` data to parse function ?). But on using @f-del code i'm not able to go inside `subscribe` method.
e.g `yourServiceToBeTested.ServiceMethodToBeTest(serviceParams).subscribe((c) => {
                        expect(c.length).toBe(11);)});`

Comment: `Unexpected token s in JSON` seems to indicate an issue with the returned JSON. What do you get when you print it to the console?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.Json.parse (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/@angular/http/src/facade/lang.js:381:53)
    at Response.json (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response.js:47:40)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] `

Comment: I meant what the JSON looks like when printed to the console.

Comment: this is what console logs :
`1. Object { MyData: Object, DataFormat: 1}
1. MyObj:Object
1. Criteria:"A"
2. GenAt:"**********"
3. NextChars:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ125./-"
4. Symbols:Array[1000]
5. __proto__:Object
2. DataFormat:1
3. __proto__:Object
`

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON. That looks like that is already parsed JSON. Maybe you try to parse it twice or similar.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 2.2.1  provide does not exist in core anymore , so we should do :

```
{
    provide : Http,
    deps : [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
    useFactory : ( backend : MockBackend, defaultOptions : BaseRequestOptions ) => {
        return new Http( backend, defaultOptions );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of @Milad's response, I found a [great tutorial on mocking http calls](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/http-and-jsonp/) for Angular 2/4 unit tests.

**searchService.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

class SearchItem {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public artist: string,
              public thumbnail: string,
              public artistId: string) {
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  apiRoot: string = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search';
  results: SearchItem[];

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {
    this.results = [];
  }

  search(term: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.results = [];
      let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
      this.jsonp.request(apiURL)
          .toPromise()
          .then(
              res => { // Success
                this.results = res.json().results.map(item => {
                  console.log(item);
                  return new SearchItem(
                      item.trackName,
                      item.artistName,
                      item.artworkUrl60,
                      item.artistId
                  );
                });
                resolve(this.results);
              },
              msg => { // Error
                reject(msg);
              }
          );
    });
  }
}
```

**searchService.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('Service: Search', () => {

  let service: SearchService;
  let backend: MockBackend;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [JsonpModule],
      providers: [
        SearchService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Jsonp,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Jsonp(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }
      ]
    });

    backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend); 

    service = TestBed.get(SearchService); 
  });
});

it('search should return SearchItems', fakeAsync(() => { 
  let response = {
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
      {
        "artistId": 78500,
        "artistName": "U2",
        "trackName": "Beautiful Day",
        "artworkUrl60": "image.jpg",
      }]
  };

  // When the request subscribes for results on a connection, return a fake response
  backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    }));
  });

  // Perform a request and make sure we get the response we expect
  service.search("U2"); 
  tick(); 

  expect(service.results.length).toBe(1); 
  expect(service.results[0].artist).toBe("U2");
  expect(service.results[0].name).toBe("Beautiful Day");
  expect(service.results[0].thumbnail).toBe("image.jpg");
  expect(service.results[0].artistId).toBe(78500);
}));
```

[Code and credit goes to Asim at CodeCraft.](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/http-and-jsonp/)