# How to write an HTTP mock unit test in Angular 2 final release?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have moved from RC4 to final release (2.1.0) and I am refactoring my unit tests to conform to 2.1.0 syntax. This is easy except for HTTP mocking.

I cannot find any examples for how to mock HTTP requests in 2.1.0

Here is an RC4 HTTP unit test. How would I re-write this in final release 2.1.0?

```
it('ngOnInit()',
  async(inject([TestComponentBuilder, XHRBackend], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder, mockBackend:MockBackend) => {
  tcb.createAsync(Route1ListComponent).then((fix:ComponentFixture<Route1ListComponent>) => {

    // THIS BLOCK OF CODE I NEED RE-WRITE TO 2.1.0
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
      (connection:MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({
              body: persons
            }
          )));
      });

    // THIS BLOCK OF CODE WILL NOT CHANGE
    let instance = fix.componentInstance;
    instance.ngOnInit();
    expect(instance.persons.length).toBe(3);
  });
})));
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use RC code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you need to do is configure the `TestBed`. There's no more `TestComponentBuilder`. With the `TestBed`, it's like configuring an `@NgModule` from scratch, just for the test environment. This means you will add the component under test to the `declarations`, add any providers to the `provider`, and any imports to the `imports`.

To configure the mock backend for `Http` provider, you would just create the `Http` from the `MockBackend`.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpModule ],
    declarations: [ RouteListComponent ],
    providers: [
      MockBackend,
      BaseRequestOptions,
      {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backend, options);
        },
        deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ]
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

That should be it for the configuration, assuming you don't need any other providers or imports I don't know about.

For the test you'll first want to make it an `async` test, as you'll be doing asynchronous operations in the test. This hasn't changed from RC, you just use `async`. If the component uses `templateUrl` (and you're not using Webpack), then you will need to call `TestBed.compileComponents()`, otherwise no need to. After that you can create the component with `TestBed.createComponent`

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<RouteListComponent>;
let component: RouteListComponent;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ... })
  .compileComponents().then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RouteListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
}));

it('...', async(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {

})))
```

Pretty much all the things above related to testing can be imported from `@angular/core/testing`. Your use of the `MockBackend` would still be the same.

Another note, you don't need to call the `component.ngOnInit`. That is called by the framework when you call `fixture.detectChanges()`

**See Also:**

- [Testing documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) for more complete examination of testing support.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, without it I could not have reached my solution outlined herein. My solution is based on this but, rightly or wrongly, avoids the use of .. async(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) .. this answer was greatly appreciated ... many thanks again :) ... if you have any feedback on my final solution it would be greatly received ... +1

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to @peeskillet for helping me reach my answer ..

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppModule} from '../../../app.module';
import {persons} from '../../../data/persons';
import {Route1ListComponent} from './route1-list.component';

// HTTP mocking imports
import {BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('route1-list.component.ts', () => {

  let fix: ComponentFixture<Route1ListComponent>;
  let instance: Route1ListComponent;
  let injector: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (pBackend: MockBackend, pOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(pBackend, pOptions);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }]
    }).compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fix = TestBed.createComponent(Route1ListComponent);
        instance = fix.componentInstance;
        injector = fix.debugElement.injector;
      });
  }));

  it('should instantiate component', () => {
    expect(instance).toEqual(jasmine.any(Route1ListComponent));
  });

  it('should have expected text', () => {
    let el = fix.debugElement.query(By.css('section.route1-list')).nativeElement;
    expect(el.textContent).toMatch(/route 1 list view/i, 'should have expected text');
  });

  it('ngOnInit()', async(() => {
    let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
    backend.connections.subscribe(
      (connection: MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({
              body: persons
            }
          )));
      });

    fix.detectChanges(); // Calls instance.ngOnInit()
    expect(instance.persons.length).toBe(3);
  }));

  it('ngOnInit() failure', async(() => {
    let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
    backend.connections.subscribe(
      (connection: MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockError(new Error('error'));
      });

    fix.detectChanges(); // Calls instance.ngOnInit()
    expect(instance.persons).toBeUndefined();
  }));

});
```

Notice that, at the time of writing, the Angular2 docs at ..

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockConnection-class.html

seem to be wrong.

When I use `Injector.resolveAndCreate` as detailed in the docs I get the error:

> Property 'resolveAndCreate' does not exist on type 'typeof Injector'.

To fix it I had to base my answer on the answer provided by @peeskillet